# Manipulation of list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started practising with some python exercises, starting with Pascal's Triangle.
I've selected lists of lists to store each of the rows.

Below is my code:

```
import sys

list = []

listoflists = [[1],[1,1]]

def pascalgeneration(func_list, cur_row, total_row):

    print("FUNCTION ENTERED\n CUR ROW \n TOTAL ROW",cur_row,total_row)
    while (cur_row < total_row):

        for iter in range(0, cur_row+1):
            if (iter == 0): 
                func_list[cur_row].append(1)
            elif(iter == cur_row):
                func_list[cur_row].append(1)
                func_list.append(list)
                break
            else:
                print ("INSIDE ELSE BLOCK\n CUR_ROW \n TOTAL_ROW\n ITER VARIABLE",cur_row,total_row,iter)
                func_list[cur_row].append(func_list[cur_row-1][iter-1]+\
                                              func_list[cur_row-1][iter])
        cur_row += 1
    print (func_list)

def main():

    no_rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows :"))
        #print (type(no_rows))
    if (no_rows==1):
        print (listoflists[0][0])
    elif(no_rows==2):
        print (listoflists[1][0],listoflists[1][1])
    else:
        listoflists.append(list)
        pascalgeneration(listoflists,2,no_rows)

    #print (listoflists)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

But when I run this code, the ouput is not as exepected:

Let the input be 5:

OUTPUT is like

```
[[1],

 [1,1],

 [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1],

 [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1],

 [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1],

 [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1]

]
```

Where as it should be

```
[

[1],

[1,1],

[1,2,1],

[1,3,3,1],

[1,4,6,4,1]

]
```

Could somebody explain me the behaviour of lists of lists, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your line 17. `func_list.append(list)`

You have put a variable `list` as an argument there. The problem is, when you do it, you're basically appending not a new empty list, like you wanted, but a link to that list you declared in line 3. So, every time you do `func_list[cur_row].append(something)`, you are appending to the same list. That's why you get a bunch of long identical lists in the result (which again, are just the same list object).

Try changing it to `func_list.append([])` in lines 17 and 35. Works more or less for me.

On a side note, **don't** use `list` and `iter` as your variable names. These are the built-in Python functions. By doing this you're shadowing them, making them inaccessible in the future. (And also makes people that use Python often confused, because we are used to seeing them as built-in functions and seeing them as variables is a bit uncomfortable)

And on an not-very-tested note, I removed the line 35 `func_list.append([])` and moved the one from line 17 right after `if iter == 10:` . That way you avoid the creation of unwanted empty list at the end of your result.

Comment: Also thanks for the valuable suggestions regarding the usage of variable names :)